# how to sum different values of a function?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need help on summation of different values of function. Here a piece of code

```
n = 4
a = np.arange(0.0,n+1,1)
def n(a):
    return 11.0+(a**2)/((2.1)**(2.0)*(1/4))

print n(a)
```

it works but I need `n(0)+n(1)+n(2)+n(3)+n(4)` as a single result

Comment: Be careful to post correctly indented code here — *especially* when posting Python code, where indentation matters for correctness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sum the elements of the array like this (look especially at the last line)

```
N = 4
a = np.linspace(0, N, N+1)

def n(a):
    return 11.0+(a**2)/((2.1)**(2.0)*(1/4))

print(n(a))
print(n(a).sum())
```

It works because `n(a)` returns a `ndarray` object (a Numpy vector) and a `ndarray` has a number of interesting pre-defined methods, among them `.sum()` whose intent is, I hope so, clear enough.

---

***Test***

```
In [7]:     N = 4 
   ...:     a = np.linspace(0, N, N+1) 
   ...:      
   ...:     def n(a): 
   ...:         return 11.0+(a**2)/((2.1)**(2.0)*(1/4)) 
   ...:      
   ...:     print(n(a)) 
   ...:     print(n(a).sum()) 
   ...:                                                                                   
[11.         11.90702948 14.62811791 19.16326531 25.51247166]
82.21088435374149
```

Comment: I see. Thank you

Comment: @Ttys If you have not external constraints that require Python 2 you could do yourself a favor and start learning Python 3 — e.g., in Python 3 if you write, at the interpreter prompt, `a = np.linspace(0, N, N+1)` next you can explore the methods available writing `a.` and pressing the TAB key twice (this doesn't work in Python 2...).

Comment: I have to use python 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
sum(n(i) for i in range(5))
```

Comment: Thanks. But I guess I did something wrong it gives numpy.ndarray' object is not callable error.

Comment: @Ttys try using more verbose variable names.  Already in your example, you are using `n` as both a function and a number.